# Laravel Global Scope not working with nested where

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to use a scope that is loaded by a trait onto a specific model so it does it on every query from that model

BUT

The query isn't working

```
public function apply(Builder $builder) {

    $builder->where(function($q){$q->whereIn('region_id', array(1,2))
            ->orWhere('manager_id', 1);
    });
}
```

This is what it is supposed to do but the page doesn't load, so I checked apache error logs and got a :

```
[core:notice] [pid 949] AH00051: child pid 2647 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

BUT
if I apply the same creteria to just a query, then it works :S

```
Client::where(function($q){
        $q->whereIn('region_id', array(1,2))
          ->orWhere('manager_id', 1);
})->get();
```

So what is wrong here?
It looks like the builder doesn't like taking functions, because it doesn't matter what I put in the function, it just doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for you - use `whereNested`:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder) {

    $builder->whereNested(function ($q) {
          $q->whereIn('region_id', array(1,2))
            ->orWhere('manager_id', 1);
    });
}
```

Explanation:

```
$builder->where
```

`Eloquent\Builder` method, causing infinite loop, because it's calling new query without scopes, which calls new query, which first boots scopes...

While:

```
$builder->whereNested
```

underyling `Query\Builder` method, that works as it is supposed to. The function call is forwarded to `Query\Builder` object, because of lack of `whereNested` method on the `Eloquent\Builder`, and magic `__call` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert for this but in the first solution you don't have `$q` defined I think so it won't work. You could try with:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder) {

    $builder->whereIn('region_id', array(1,2))->orWhere('manager_id', 1);
}
```

or

```
public function apply(Builder $builder) {

    $builder->where(function() use $builder {$builder->whereIn('region_id', array(1,2))
            ->orWhere('manager_id', 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: The where stuff needs to be between (), that's why I'm using a function otherwise it's not possible in eloquent, when using a function it will put eveything in that function between ()

Comment: @Mazzy I've edited my answer, probably it won't work but you could try